# Why does java.io.URL strip out the last folder?

Tags: java, url

I've encountered a bug in a library my application is using. I've narrowed the issue down to the behavior of the [`java.net.URL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) class and how the library uses it to look up resources.

When I run the following code, the output is `file:/root/myfile.xml` instead of `file:/root/folder/myfile.xml`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
    String location = "file:///root/folder";
    String spec = "myfile.xml";

    URL context = new URL(location);
    URL url = new URL(context, spec);

    System.out.println(url);
}
```

I get the expected output if I append a slash to `location`.

I'm curious, why does `java.net.URL` behave like this?

Comment: @bmargulies Thanks. I updated the question, though the behavior is the same.

Comment: I think you just need to leave the `/` on the end of the location string...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the java.net.url page:

> An application can also specify a "relative URL", which contains only
>   enough information to reach the resource relative to another URL.
>   Relative URLs are frequently used within HTML pages. For example, if
>   the contents of the URL:
>
> ```
>  http://java.sun.com/index.html
> ```
>
> contained within it the relative URL:
>
> ```
>  FAQ.html
> ```
>
> it would be a shorthand for:
>
> ```
>  http://java.sun.com/FAQ.html
> ```

So by leaving off the trailing `/` from `location`, you're not specifying to the URL constructor that it is the root for the spec, rather than a relative path to be joined with.